# Python 2.7: Multiprocessing, Queue and Join

Tags: python, join, queue, multiprocessing

I parallelized my Python 2.7 script by using the multiprocessing module like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process

def func(input_queue, result_queue):
    my_object = input_queue.get()
    # do something
    result_queue.put([my_object, 0])
    print "finished"


procs = []
chuncks = 4
input_queue = Queue()
result_queue = Queue()
j = len(my_objects)/chuncks

for i in range(chuncks):
    input_queue.put(list(my_objects[(i*j):(i+1)*j]]))

for i in range(chuncks):
    proc = Process(target=func, args=(input_queue, result_queue))
    procs.append(proc)
    proc.start()
    print proc.pid

for proc in procs:
    proc.join()

while not result_queue.empty():
    print result_queue.get()
```

`my_object` is an instance of a class `my_class` written by me.

My Problem is:
Depending on the implementation `my_class`, my code works or does not. If I define `my_class` simply as follows

```
class my_class(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print "bla"
```

everything is fine. But 'in reality', `my_class` is more complex (has several attributes). Executing the above code with the real implementation of `my_class` leads to the following output:

```
1545
1546
1547
1548
finished
finished
finished
finished
```

Then, it stucks while waiting for `proc.join()`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Can you try to give us the smallest possible program which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: In this example, the output should be the content of 'result_queue' (- in fact, my function 'func' is more complex than in my posting here: I use the attributes of my_object for some calculations and pass my_object and the result of the calculations (instead of 0) to result_queue.)

Answer (score 0):

try to use different queue

```
m = multiprocessing.Manager()
queue1 = m.Queue()
```